# SAS: Send email once tables have been modified/refreshed

Tags: sas

I am looking for a solution which will monitor (using do loop) dictionary.tables for the latest modified date (modate) of a particular table and once the modified date (modate) equals today's date i want to be notified via the email facility in SAS.

Can this be done???

Many thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Is there a specific part of this that you can't get to work?

Comment: Step 1) Using SQL, i can run a small program which displays the last modified date (modate) of 3 tables which are then appended, this part i would like to be monitored automatically by a loop of some kind rather then having to run the program every time i want to check.

Comment: Step 2) Once the last modified date for each table equals today's date i would like to be notified via SAS email facility. I have some code which does send an email however this needs to be only sent if the condition is met, the condition being something like-  IF modate = today then send email. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though you need to define a simple little macro incorporating your existing code:

```
/* Define a macro that sleeps in a loop until your condition is met */
%macro wait_then_email;
  %local EMAIL_CONDITION SLEEP;
  %let EMAIL_CONDITION = 0;
  %do %while(&EMAIL_CONDITION = 0);
    /* Insert logic here that sets &EMAIL_CONDITION to 1 based on moddate */

    /* Wait for 1 minute if condition not met*/
    %if &EMAIL_CONDITION = 0 %then %let SLEEP = %sysfunc(sleep(60,1));
  %end;
  /*Insert email generation code here*/
%mend;

/* Run the macro! */
%wait_then_email;
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the logic that sets the &EMAIL_CONDITION to 1 based on modate please???